# c# linq with selectMany to sql statement

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I dont know how to translate this linq code to a normal SQL query. I know the first part and that I need to make an inner join but I dont know where exaclty.

How does this linq query Looks like in SQL query?

```
context.DataTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID).Roles.SelectMany(x => x.RoleToExtensions.Select(y => y.Extension)).ToList();
```

Comment: Why is `node.js` relevant to this question? It seems like it's only about SQL and LINQ.

Comment: oh yeah, you are rigth. I just need the query for nodejs programm and instinctive added a nodejs tag

Comment: Can you show the class models or SQL Tables with the relevant columns - e.g. keys associating DataTable to Roles and Roles to Extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code in your DbContext class and run the code. The query will be shown in the output window of Visual Studio. 
(need to install nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, and add the respective namespaces)

```
      public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
          = new LoggerFactory(new[] { new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true) });


      protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {
#if DEBUG
         optionsBuilder
             .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
             .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
#endif
      }
```

Or if you just need a simple sql of the LINQ query:

```
SELECT re.Extension FROM roletoextension re 
WHERE re.RoleId IN 
(SELECT RoleId FROM Role r 
WHERE r.DataTableId = {ID})
```