# What will be the equivalent sql query for this code?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

This code is giving inaccurate results and I need to change it but I do not understand what the whole code is doing.

I read about defaultifempty and its implementation. I read the documentation but I could not find the answer to the question.

```
 var records = from entity in _db.InventoryDetails
                          from am in _db.AccountMeters
                            .Where(am => entity.SerialNumber == (am.SerialNumber ?? am.RemoteId.ToString())).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          from ac in _db.Accounts
                       .Where(ac => ac.AccountId == am.AccountId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          from i in _db.Inventories
                            .Where(idd => idd.ProjectId == projectid)
                            .Where(idd => idd.InventoryId == entity.InventoryId)
                          from u in _db.Users
                            .Where(e => e.Id == (entity.InstallerId ?? entity.PrevInstaller)).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

It does not give error just the query is giving wrong result. If I can find sql equivalent for the code then I can find out what he was trying to do and then find out business requirement and re code.

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57957378) to view the sql query

Comment: I understand when it is just where condition, here there are joins I can not figure out which one. .Where(am => entity.SerialNumber == (am.SerialNumber ?? am.RemoteId.ToString() in this code is it taking am.serialnumber as the default if remoteid is empty?

Comment: There is a very handy tool called Linqpad (https://www.linqpad.net/) that can help you go between LINQ and SQL, either direction. I suggest you become friends with it!  Once it's running, you will need to provide it with a valid connection to a database, and then you can run  your LINQ statement. In the process, it will show you the SQL that was executed against the database.

Comment: Check this answer, Shows you various ways to see the genereated sql from your linq code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190620/how-to-see-generated-sql-from-a-linq-query

Comment: The SQL query will be much longer and harder to understand than the LINQ query. You better put some effort in understanding LINQ in general. If you keep working with LINQ that's a useful investment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can get SQL code which will be generated by your code through calling `ToString()` method:

```
var records = from entity in _db.InventoryDetails
    // the other code is omitted for the brevity
var sqlCode = records.ToString(); // here your generated SQL code
```

Answer (score 0):

With EF 6 and beyond, you can use

`context.Database.Log = Console.Write;`

to write the SQL to the console.